# Trying to get Call Stack at a Breakpoint using python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, xmlhttprequest

I'd like to obtain the call stack at the point when a media packet of a YouTube video is obtained by the browser.
Since I am using Selenium in Python3, is there any way to get this using selenium?
[image]

Here's some code I've written:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

# from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities
import time

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capabilities["loggingPrefs"] = {"performance": "ALL"}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    desired_capabilities=capabilities, executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
)

# driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlzCi0x9uJw")
# time.sleep(5)
# print(driver.requests[9].response.body)

link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("=")
link.click()
time.sleep(3)
x = driver.get_log("browser")
print(x)

driver.close()
```

What I am trying to get is the list of methods/functions (the call stack) that were called to obtain the segment of content being streamed.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. 
Actually, there is no significant code that I have written. Adding it to my question anyways.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium: Do you think you can help me with this?